# Java spring MVC - Student database. Not able to edit the student document

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have created a java spring MVC web application for student management, Iam able to add the student . But when i click on edit student it shows HTTP 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Controller :

```
  package com.akhil.controller;
  import java.util.Map;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
  import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
  importorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ModelAndViewResolver;
  import com.akhil.model.Student;
  import com.akhil.service.StudentService;

  @Controller
  public class StudentController {

  @Autowired
  private StudentService studentService;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String setupForm(ModelMap model){
    Student student = new Student();
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    model.addAttribute("studentList", studentService.getAllStudent());
    return "student";
   }

  @RequestMapping(value="/student.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)

  public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult    result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){

    Student studentResult = new Student();
    studentService.add(student);
    map.put("student", studentResult);
    map.put("studentList", studentService.getAllStudent());

    return "student";
   }

  @RequestMapping(value="/editstudent", method=RequestMethod.GET)

public String editstudent(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){

    Student studentResult = new Student();
    studentService.edit(student.getStudentId());
    map.put("student",studentResult);
    map.put("studentList", studentService.getAllStudent());
    return "student";
    }
  }
```

View:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Student Management</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Students Data</h1>
    <form:form action="student.do" method="POST" commandName="student">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="studentId">Student ID:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="studentId" value="${Student.studentID}" />       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" value="${Student.firstname}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last name</td>
        <td><form:input path="lastname" value="${Student.lastname}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Year Level</td>
        <td><form:input path="yearLevel" value="${Student.yearLevel}" />  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
   <br>
   <table border="1">
  <tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>First name</th>
<th>Last name</th>
<th>Year level</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${studentList}" var="student">
    <tr>
        <td>${student.studentId}</td>
        <td>${student.firstname}</td>
        <td>${student.lastname}</td>
        <td>${student.yearLevel}</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="editstudent.html?   studentId=${student.studentId}">Edit</a> | <a href="deletestudent.html?studentIds=${student.studentId}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>CRUDWebAppMavenized</display-name>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The java method editstudent() accepts get request mapped to editstudent.html? studentId=${student.studentId}, I don't think studentId can be converted to ModelAttribute Student. You are not sending other fields of the student, like first name or last name. In addition, edit should be a post or put request instead of get.

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editstudent", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editstudent(@ModelAttribute Student student,BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map)
```

this approach is wrong you cant get a `studentObject` from a `GET` Request,
since you are trying to edit  the object i suggest using a `POST` request remove the `@modelAttribute` annotation inside the method parameter
this annotation forms an object from the fields inside the form.
`BindingResult`  collects `errors` if it cant form an object from the incoming request.
since you are not submitting a form you dont need any of them.

but you can fetch the student object from the database using the `id` you are getting from the `url`

```
public String editstudent(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model){
 student studentobj = studentservice.get(id);//assuming that this loads the object from database;
 model.addAttribute("student",studentobj);
 return "student";
}
```

and now you can represent the student details inside the `student.jsp`
then have a form to edit those details.

Comment: Dont pass the object which needs to be edited.pass the id of the object then fetch the object from the database using the id. And finally pass that object to the edit view

Comment: This is my function

@RequestMapping(value="/editstudent", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String editstudent(@RequestParam("studentId") int studentID, Model model) {
  
  Student student = studentService.getStudent(studentID);
  model.addAttribute(student);
  return "student1";
  }

Comment: Is student1 is your page name. Return the page name which you need to viewed. And change this part too. 'Model.addAttribute("student",student);'